# Is a $\Omega$-Spectrum a connective one?

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectra

I can't find this result anywhere, but it seems pretty straightforward. I want to avoid silly mistakes, but I can't see any fault. I'd love to receive some feedback

Let $X$ be a $\Omega$-spectrum (of compactly generated topological spaces). By definition for $q<0$, $$\pi_q(X)=\lim_k \pi_{k+q <k}X_k$$

But since $\pi_i(X_k)\cong \pi_{i}(\Omega X_{k+1})\cong \pi_{i+1}(X_{k+1})$ the spaces are more and connected, in particular, $X_k$ is $k-1$-connected and therefore $\pi_q(X)=0$.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $\Omega$-spectrum is not necessarily a connective one.  In your argument, there is no reason "the spaces are more and [more] connected".  For a concrete example, consider the $K$-theory spectrum $KU$.  In its usual incarnation (with $BU \times \mathbb{Z}$ even and $\Omega(BU \times \mathbb{Z})$ odd), it is already a $\Omega$-spectrum by Bott periodicity.  But it's 2-periodic, so its homotopy groups extend infinitely in negative degrees.

In general, remember then every spectrum can be converted into a $\Omega$-spectrum by a telescope construction, without changing its homotopy groups.  So if every $\Omega$-spectrum was connective, this would mean then every spectrum is connective, which should strike you as patently false.  This gives another bunch of counterexamples: take any spectrum, desuspend it a bunch of times so that it has negative homotopy groups, and then "$\Omega$-spectrify".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! could you please point me out what's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the "spaces" do not necessarily get more connected, and $X_k$ need not be $(k-1)$-connected.

Comment: therefore the formula I wrote in my question is necessarily false, I thought it was true, I mean, is the usual loop-space plus adjunction

Comment: No, your formula is fine; it's the implications after it that are unclear.

Comment: well apply the formula for $i=-1$ and you get that $\pi_1 (X_k)=0$, and then inductively you prove that the more $k$ increase, the more connected is the space

Comment: I agree that you have $\pi_i X_k \cong \pi_{i-1} X_{k-1} \cong \cdots \cong \pi_0 X_{k-i}$ (which need not be $0$).  Unfortunately, the induction breaks down at $i = 0$.  Your formula (more specifically, the "adjunction") only works for $i \geq 0$.

Answer (score -1):

Direct answers would be helpful. I believe you are saying for connective $\Omega$-spectrum $X$, $\pi_i(X)=0$ for all $i\leq -1$. For non connective $\Omega$-spectrum, there are nontrivial negative homotopy groups.